# #document iFrame access using Playwright

Tags: iframe, playwright, playwright-test

[image: Page source]

How to access the virutal document #document contents using playwright ? I tried using iFrame and Pagelocator. However, I am unable to reach document location.

Is there an option in Playwright to approach this?
This is the page URL - https://sites.google.com/view/pinnednote/home

Comment: "I tried using iFrame and Pagelocator"--please share these attempts as [mcve]s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have `frame_locator` for python or `frameLocator` for javascript.

Here an example in your page (Using python)

```
# Import needed libs
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

# We initiate the playwright page
p = sync_playwright().start()
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
context = browser.new_context()
page = context.new_page()

# Navigate
page.goto("https://sites.google.com/view/pinnednote/home")

# We get the first iframe
iframe1 = page.frame_locator("//iframe[@jsname='WMhH6e']")

# We get the iframe inside the first iframe
iframe2 = iframe1.frame_locator("#innerFrame")

# We get the iframe inside the second iframe
iframe3 = iframe2.frame_locator("#userHtmlFrame")

# We print the title of this third iframe
print(iframe3.locator("//title").inner_text())
```

The page has a lot of iframes being honest.

About managing frames with playwright: [Playwirght frameLocator](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-framelocator)